# Distribution of the intersection between a grid and a circle

Tags: geometry

I am looking for the expression of the distribution of the intersection of a grid and a circle. The problems looks like that:

[image]

Let's say the circle has radius R and the grid has unit spacing. Is there a formula for the average distribution of their intersection points viewed from the center of the disk, as in an angular distribution.

It has to be invariant under $\frac{\pi}{2}$ rotations and intuitively I am expecting more intersections along the diagonals but I don't know how it depends on R.

I am not expecting an analytical expression much more a quantitative behaviour or an asymptotic.

Comment: Do you mean the points where the circle intersects the vertices of the grid, or also the edges?

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly, you have a circle of radius $R$ centered at the origin and want to know which circle points have integer $x$ or $y$ coordinate.

The answer is quite immediate: a point on the circle in the first quadrant ($0\le\theta\le \pi/2$, where angle $\theta$ is measured from the $x$-axis) has coordinates $x=R\cos\theta$ and $y=R\sin\theta$, so that the angles corresponding to integer coordinates in the first quadrant are:
$$
\theta=\arccos{n\over R}\quad\hbox{and}\quad
\theta=\arcsin{n\over R},\quad\hbox{with}\quad
0\le n\le\left\lfloor{R}\right\rfloor.
$$
Of course you also have the symmetric of these points in the other quadrants.

**EDIT**

The distribution in the limit $R\to+\infty$ (see [MvG's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1492070)) is easy to find, because in that case $n/R$ varies smoothly and approaches $(x+y)/R$, so that
$$
{n\over R}=\cos\theta+\sin\theta,
\quad \hbox{for}\ 
0\le \theta\le{\pi\over2},
\quad \hbox{in the limit}\ 
R\to+\infty.
$$

Comment: Thanks for helping reformulating my problem, but shouldn't be $\lfloor R\rfloor$ in your inequality?

Comment: Yes, of course: I wrote in a hurry and didn't check. Corrected now.

Answer (score 1):

> I am expecting more intersections along the diagonals

You are right. Using [Aretino's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1491419/35416), for $R=10.000$ you get this histogram:

[image: Histogram for R=10000 with 100 bins]

> but I don't know how it depends on $R$

Qualitatively, this doesn't seem to depend too much on $R$, as you can see with $R=1.000$:

[image: Histogram for R=1000 with 50 bins]

Of course, the smoothing of the histogram, i.e. the ratio between $R$ and the number of bins, has a large impact on how apparent this effect is. E.g. with $R=100$ and $100$ bins it's very hard to see this shape:

[image: Histogram for R=100 with 100 bins]

I guess there should be a nice (and perhaps even closed form) description for the shape of the histogram curve you'd get in the limit for an infinite number of bins, and an “even more infinite” size $R$, but I don't know how to find it.

Comment: I've just edited my answer to address your last question.